# Create a map from the loopback model find output

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I am querying my db using simple loopback model find. e.g.

```
app.models.User.find({
    where: {userId: id, status: 'active'},
    fields: ['key', value']}).then(function(userData){

});
```

Here userData is an array. I know that 'key' will be unique.So is there a way that i can get the result in a map with 'key' 'value' pair?

Thanks

Comment: What is the database? Mongo?

Comment: its postgresql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an array because the [`find`](http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-find) method returns an array (see the parameters the callback is invoked with).

If the query returned at least one item, your first key-value pair will be at `userData[0]`.
If not, then your array is empty and you need to modify the query.